# Issue displaying an error message in the correct div while using Parsley Js

Tags: html, error-handling, parsley.js

Am using Parsley.js to perform some frontend custom validation which is working fine. When there is an error it is being displayed at the bottom of the div but **I want the error to be displayed inside the span which has a class of help-block**. The span class also holds error messages from the backend code which works fine.

I want to use the same span-class to display errors from parsley.js custom validator.

**Layout**

```
 <div class="form-line registar2 move {{ $errors->has('kra') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" >
      <input id="kra" placeholder="KRA PIN Number *" type="text-area" class="form-input" name="kra" value="{{ old('kra') }}" maxlength="12" required data-parsley-kra = ''>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
      @if ($errors->has('kra'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('kra') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
    </div>
```

**Parsleyjs Custom validator**

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('kra', {
  validateString: function(value) {
    return true == (/[A-Z]\d{9,}[A-Z]$/.test(value));
  },
  messages: {
    en: 'Please insert a valid PIN number e.g <b> A123456789A </b>'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The setting `data-parsley-errors-container` allows you to change where Parsley puts the error messages.